# Why does printing a file with unicode characters does not produce the emojis?

Tags: python, unicode

the content of the text file is

```
u'\u26be\u26be\u26be'
```

When I run the script...

```
import codecs
f1 = codecs.open("test1.txt", "r", "utf-8")
text = f1.read()
print text
str1 = u'\u26be\u26be\u26be'
print(str1)
```

I get the output...

```
u'\u26be\u26be\u26be'
⚾⚾⚾
```

Question: Why is that a string, which the same content as the file, is able to produce the emojis properly?

Comment: Why doesn't you typing "u'\u26be\u26be\u26be'" here render emojis? Because the text "u'\u26be\u26be\u26be'" is the text "u'\u26be\u26be\u26be'", not a bunch of emojis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input file is required to have unicode escapes you will need to filter it like so:

```
with open("test1.txt", "r") as f1:
    text = f1.read()
    print unicode(text, 'unicode_escape')
    str1 = u'\u26be\u26be\u26be'
    print(str1)
```

No need to import other libraries.

Answer (score 8):

File content `u'\u26be\u26be\u26be'` is like `r"u'\u26be\u26be\u26be'"`. In other words, characters of  `u`, `\`, `u`, `2`, ...

You can convert such string to the string `⚾⚾⚾` using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
import codecs

with codecs.open("test1.txt", "r", "utf-8") as f1:
    text = ast.literal_eval(f1.read())
print text
...
```

But, why does the file contain such string (`u'\u26be\u26be\u26be'`) instead of `⚾⚾⚾`? Maybe you need to consider redesigning file saving part.

Comment: I read and save the file in R. I guess it is the reason for the contents of the file getting saved as `u'\u26be\u26be\u26be'`